# 'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated in Java, is there an alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecation-warning

I've got a line of code like this:

```
val smsRetrieverStatus = extrasObj?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status
```

But it's now deprecated as shown:

[image]

Is there any alternative way of doing this without getting deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 8):

If you read the method documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle#get(java.lang.String)), it says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 33. Use the type-safe specific
> APIs depending on the type of the item to be retrieved, eg.
> getString(java.lang.String)

So, they're telling you to stop using the generic `get()` method, and instead use a type-specific one -- `getString()`, `getInt()`, `getLong()`, etc.

**Update**:
If you have a custom class or data type, then you'll need to implement your own logic to serialize that class (maybe use something like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)). And once you've serialized it into a `String`, you can then use `getString()`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Sadly, this won't work for me since they don't have a getStatus. But I can see how this answer would work for other people. So thanks anyways :)

Comment: Same for me, we use Bundle for transfering custom object so none of the available methods is suitable. Method get(String key, Class<T> clazz) is not public. :-/

Comment: @Amy But it does have such method. It has `getParcelable <T>` and `getSerializable <T>` - and your object must be one of those in order to be placed in the `Bundle` in the first place

Comment: @Agent_L Interesting, I'll have another go at it in a month's time when I'm back on building that part of Android :) Thank you!

Comment: those sugested apis require android 33!

Comment: Of course they do -- the old ones were deprecated as of API 33

Answer (score 2):

You can try another method

```
val status = extrasObj?.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS, Status::class.java)
```

**Note that this method is not stable and sometimes throws NPE. So you'd better catch and handle the NPE.**

Comment: What exception exactly?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski NullPointerException due to some call of the method `java.lang.Class.isInterface()` internally in `android.os.Parcel`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any ticket about that?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski seems someone already reported similar issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930